# Probability seems wrong using Python randint

Tags: python, python-2.7, random, probability

I'm using Python 2.7 to generate two random numbers, both **1-100** (including **1** and **100**), and if they are the same, an event occurs. I would think that the probability of this would be **1/10000** because

**1/100 * 1/100 = 1/10000**

but the number times that it takes for the two numbers to match up is usually between 10-200. Why does this happen and is there any way to fix it?

---

Here's my full code:

```
import random
p5SickGen1 = random.randint(1,100)
p5SickGen2 = random.randint(1,100)
counter = 0
while p5SickGen1 != p5SickGen2:
    counter += 1
    p5SickGen1 = random.randint(1,100)
    p5SickGen2 = random.randint(1,100)

print(counter)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@jgritty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28336196/793428) said earlier, your assumption is *wrong*.

The probability would not be **1/10000** because you are selecting from two different sets of numbers at the same time, which doesn't mean that you are picking a number from a set of numbers twice.

You can easily find the solution like this;

The number of the possibilities of getting same numbers are;

```
(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5), ..., (100, 100) = 100
```

Your sample space is **100*100 = 10000**. Thus the probability of getting same numbers in one pick;

```
100 / 10000 = 0.01
```

Hope this helps.

Btw, for those who are interested in learning the basics of probability, you can start from [here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/probability.html).

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption is wrong.  There's nothing wrong here.

The odds of the numbers coming up the same twice in a row is simply 1 in 100.

Now, if you pick a specific number, say 42.  The odds of getting 42 both times is 1 in 10000.